# Handling href in Jinja with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jinja2

I'm displaying a list of items provided in a variable called workshop by looping over each item in a sequence

```
{% for car in workshop %}
    <div id="newDiv" >
    <a class="carsInWorkshop" title = "{{car.carId}}" href="./getPriceforCar/{{car.carId}}">{{ car.carType }}</a>    
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When somebody clicks on the items with hyperlink

Item1

Item2

Item3

Rather then directly routing the href call to my flask app, I want to make an ajax call, and handle the results

```
$(".carsInWorkshop").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(".carsInWorkshop").attr('href'));
        loadPrice($(".carsInWorkshop").attr('href'));
    });

 loadPrice = function(link, callback) {
   console.log('loading price for ' + link);
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: link,
       cache: false,
       xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
       },
       success: function(data) { 
        $('div#pop-up-price').show();
        $('#carId').val(data.price);  
       }
    });
 }
```

But, for some reason whenever I click on Item 2 or Item 3, results are always displayed for href for Item1. href always contain the carId for first item.

If I route calls directly to flask, I get the right carId based on item click. So, it seems the handling for jquery is not correct.
 
Is there a special handling for jquery when working in Jinja for accessing href from "for loops"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(".carsInWorkshop")` always returns 3 elements and `.attr`
returns the href of the first element

I have a working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gx63x6kc/1)

By using `event.target` you ensure that you retrieve the correct element, in this case the one the user clicked.

Even though this will work I recommend you store the type somewhere else. Rather change the href to "" and use [jquery data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to attach the type directly to the element so it can easily be retrieved later.

`$('#card-type-type1').data('type', '<some_type>')`

`$(event.target).data('type')`

You can place this in a script block in jinja

**Edit**: I have updated the jsfiddle and sample code

Comment: jquery.data seems like a good way of storing key values on an element and retrieving it later but not sure how I can use it my case when href will be generated dynamically. Also, I don't understand what's $data is here.

Comment: Also, are we storing href in storage "type" for every element with id  #card-type-type1? Something like this $data($('#card-type-type1'), 'type', 'href'). any chance you can show it with working example?

Comment: Yes we are. The data will be stored on every element that matches the selector, 1 in this case. I have updated the answer, I misunderstood the jquery data api.